# Getting type mismatch error on passing odd value from one array to another

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to extract odd elements from an array and assigning it to another array.

```
Dim Array2 As Variant

n = 1

For i To Array1
    If n Mod 2 = 0 Then
         Array2(i) = Array1(i)
    End If
    n = n + 1
Next i
```

Can please somebody suggest.

Comment: What is `Array1`? From its name and later references, it sounds like it should be an array, but that wouldn't be right because then you'd be trying to count from `I` (an integer possibly??) to array. Computers only count numbers, so maybe you really want `For i to UBound(Array1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example to filter the values present at an odd index to a new array:

```
Dim Array1(), Array2(), i As Long

Array1 = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

ReDim Array2(LBound(Array1) To UBound(Array1) \ 2)

For i = LBound(Array1) To UBound(Array1) Step 2
    Array2(i \ 2) = Array1(i)
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop should go from Lbound(Array1) to Ubound(Array1).  Also you need to declare the size of Array 2

```
Dim Array2 As Variant
Redim Array2 (lbound(Array1) to (Ubound(Array1)/2) + 1)
n = 1

For i = lbound(Array1) to Ubound(Array1)
    If n Mod 2 = 0 Then
         Array2((i/2)-.5) = Array1(i)
    End If
n = n + 1
Next i
```

Comment: But when I see the output in Console. Array2 consist of all odd element plus empty even elements. I only want odd elements. Thanks

Comment: Scott, this doesn't work. It still gives my those empty even elements. Plus it removes the second odd element as 2/1 - 0.5 = 0.5 and there is no such location as 0.5 in array. Either 0, 1,2,3 ...and so on

Comment: Are you sure you used the updated version?  You may need to refresh the screen.

Comment: Thanks Scott for your inputs. But it seems that we have to also add something to delete those empty positions. Though the solution provided by Michael did work.